# How to create EditText background %100 transparent with bottom line

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, drawable

I need to create Edittext drawable background with %100 percent transparent and has only colored bottom line 2dp. Is there any way to make this component.

The bellow code with constant background. I need transparent background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary2" />
            <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: add "00" to any color to make it tranperent eg. #005B02FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <!--background color -->
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="-3dp"
    android:right="-3dp"
    android:left="-3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000" /> 
            <!-- color and size of the border -->
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is color for a transparency in android. Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
         <item>
             <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                 <solid android:color="#FFffffff" />
                 <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
             </shape>
         </item>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                 <solid android:color="@color/background" />
            </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```